# refresh list displayed in child component

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ionic4

hello everyone I have home component and its child list component from home component when clicking menu icon i can choose an item and based on this choice I get rendered to home/list and then I get a displayed list based on the choice but in my case its displayed correctly only in the first time but if i change the choice i still have the same list displayed here is some screenshots to help you understand..
[here I have already chosen "migration" from menu and the list is displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppLIJ.png)

[and here its the list displayed from an api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n4r8.png)

[and this describes my problem after choosing the list diplayed without refreshing the data to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPgbs.png)

```
export class ListPage implements OnInit {
  filter: string;
  toolbarTitle: string;
  toolbarColor: string;
  itemIcon: string;
  ots: OtModel[]
  listOtDispl: OtModel[] = [];
  currentUser: Utilisateur
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private otService: OtService, private utilisateurService: UtilisateurService) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.filter = params["myParameter"]
    });
    this.utilisateurService.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.currentUser = x);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListOt()
  }
  getListOt() {
    this.otService.getAllOt().pipe(map(
      ((listOt: OtModel[]) => listOt.filter(
        (ot: OtModel) => ot.typeOt === this.filter
      ))
    )).
    subscribe(
      (listOt: OtModel[]) => {
        this.ots = listOt
        console.log(this.ots)
      })
  }
```

HomePage.ts

```js
export class HomePage {
  currentUser: Utilisateur
  typesOt: TypeOtModel[];
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private utilisateurService: UtilisateurService,
    private otService: OtService) {
    this.utilisateurService.currentUser.subscribe(x => this.currentUser = x);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTypeOts()
    console.log(this.typesOt)
  }
  Goto(menu: OtModel) {
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        myParameter: menu.typeOt,
      }
    };
    if (menu.typeOt == 'RLA Reservation') {
      this.router.navigate(["home/rla"], navigationExtras);
    } else
      this.router.navigate(["home/list"], navigationExtras);
    console.log(navigationExtras.queryParams.myParameter)
  }
  getTypeOts() {
    this.otService.getTypeOt().subscribe(data => {
      this.typesOt = data as TypeOtModel[]
    })
    console.log(this.typesOt)
  }
}
```

listpage.html

```html
<ion-header>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item  button *ngFor="let item of ots  ">
         <!-- <ion-icon name="{{itemIcon}}" slot="end" class ="customIcon" color="{{toolbarColor}}" ></ion-icon> -->
         <ion-label>
            <h2>{{item.idDem}}</h2>
            <!-- <p>{{item.description}}</p> -->
         </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { 
    this.filter =params["myParameter"] 
    this.getListOt();
});
```

Or

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
     this.getListOt();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. in my case i tried ionViewWillEnter() but the list isnt refreshing..i moved getListOt() to constructor and it worked as wished thank you!